# Error in civix generate:api "You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time"

Tags: civix

When attempting to run this:

```
civix generate:api Invoice Create
```

It creates an /api/v3/Invoice folder but doesn't create any files. Instead I get the following:

> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session
>   module's ini settings at this time in
>   /home/ubuntu/civix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/NativeFileSessionHandler.php
>   line 56

Civix works for me otherwise; I can create extensions, pages, etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit this one last month, and created a bug for it: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16218

Are you using WordPress, by any chance?

Comment: Yep, it occured for me on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can create manually the Create.php file that contains civicrm_api3_invoice_create()

Check the api/v3 folder in the core for examples (eg. the email one)

As for civix, do you have the latest version? if it's the case, fill a bug on github

Comment: @Andrew's answer and bug filed match the exact issue I'm having. I looked at the Email Create example, but it calls existing api functions. In this case I'm asking civix to create a new API endpoint in order to expose some custom functions to the CMS, per http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-AddanAPIfunction.

Comment: my point was that you don't need civix to create these, you can manually create the file with the right function and it will end up working the same

Comment: Ah, I thought perhaps something special was required for exposing my own api functions, as the wiki said "Note that the parameters and return values must be processed in a particular way (as demonstrated by the auto-generated file)."

Comment: nope, but it's expecting the name of the file and location and function within to follow a specific format. Checkout the api/v3 on civi for examples (mail.php for instance for a generic one, assuming you have a dao/bao already)